# Is there any study of people’s intuitive ability to accurately make judgments about other people immediately?

Tags: intuition

I would like to know about topics related to micro-expressions but far broader: how is it that you sometimes feel you can immediately know that a person is for example kind or worth asking a certain question?

Are there any findings that recurrent biologically based personality types are associated with unexpected markers we subconsciously pick up on like body language, gait, resting facial expression, tone of voice, manner of speech, or even style of dress, or more subtle factors like pheromones, or perhaps studies confirming effects without known causes, as of yet?

https://www.e-elgar.com/shop/gbp/handbook-of-intuition-research-9781848448889.html